# How to pass in extra parameters (org name) to Devise Invitable email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

In my application I have users and sites (think of it like users and organizations). There's a lookup table the sits between them called SiteUser. In SiteUser:

`belongs_to :site`

`belongs_to :user`

`before_validation :set_user_id, if: ->() { email != nil }`

`def set_user_id
    existing_user = User.find_by(email: email)
    self.user = if existing_user.present?
                  UserMailer.notify_existing_user(site, existing_user).deliver_now unless Rails.env.test?
                  existing_user
                else
                  User.invite!(email: email)
                end
  end`

I need the subject of the email that gets generated to include the site name. "Example Company has invite you to join their site!"

And in the email body I also need the site title.

I am confused on how to get the site parameter over to `devise invitable`. As you can see in the code above, if the user who is being invited to the site already exists in our system, I use my own mailer in which I pass in the `site` and the `existing_user` so I have access to it in my mailer view.

`class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_existing_user(site, user)
    @site = site
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "You've been given access to #{@site.title} in the Dashboard."
  end
end`

I cannot figure out how to accomplish this similarly with the devise invitable mailer, which is used when the user doesn't already exist in the system.

Any help you could provide would be incredibly appreciated!

Comment: probably not the answer you're hoping for, but assuming that there's some sort of "current site" logic, you could store the "current_site_id" on your user and then query it that way from within your mailer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I went about accomplishing this was to add a temporary/virtual attribute on User called `invite_site_name`. Because the problem was that `site` wasn't an attribute of User, so I could not send `site` in to `User.invite!`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :invite_site_name
```

and then in my `CustomDeviseMailer` I had access to it:

```
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer

  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views

  def invitation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    opts[:subject] = "#{record.invite_site_name} has invited you to their Dashboard! Instructions inside!"

    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always override devise's subject_for method. Found this on the gems issues, that also suggests another way:
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/issues/660#issuecomment-277242853

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was looking at this and it mostly makes sense to me. Thank you for sharing this. I'm stuck on understanding how get the site id passed into the method I'm overriding though (if I pass the side id in I can do a lookup and grab the site object in the mailer).


`User.invite!(email: email, site: site)`

Results in `unknown attribute 'site' for User. Because the user has_many sites. But I just want to get that ID passed through there so I can query it in my CustomDeviseMailer.

Comment: Try `self.site`, since you are inside SiteUser. Or set a variable in the beginning of the method, like `invitation_site = self.site` and then reference `invitation_site` inside your `invite!` call.